How can I extract the hyperlink anchor stored in a \newlabel in the aux file?
Suppose in my .aux file this is generated:
\newlabel{myNiceLemma}{{2}{1}{}{theorem.2}{}}

Is there a command to which I can give myNiceLemma and get out the anchor theorem.2 in this case?
Note: Is there any way to extract the values stored in newlabel is similar. but there the goal was to extract the number. I want to get the anchor.
MWE:
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,hyperref,amsthm,cleveref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\parindent0cm
\parskip1em
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{mythm}
  Test.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}\label{myNiceLemma}
  Nice.
\end{lemma}

ref: \ref{myNiceLemma}

ref*: \ref*{myNiceLemma}

getrefnumber: \getrefnumber{myNiceLemma}

Cref: \Cref{myNiceLemma}

But how can I get ``\texttt{theorem.2}'' here?
\end{document}


(Note: I would prefer a solution working in TexLive 2022 - which I mention because somewhere I read that anchors and labels are synced/changed in more recent versions of hyperref etc)
(Context: I admit that I am asking an X-Y question. Actually I want to make an absolute link to https://example.com/file.pdf#theorem.2 - but \externaldocument from xr-hyper did not work for me.)

The refcount package has also commands to extract the other fields.

You do
\getrefbykeydefault{myNiceLemma}{anchor}{??}

but it's obviously better to define a suitable command.
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\newcommand{\getanchor}[1]{%
  \getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{??}%
}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{mythm}
  Test.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}\label{myNiceLemma}
  Nice.
\end{lemma}

ref: \ref{myNiceLemma}

ref*: \ref*{myNiceLemma}

getrefnumber: \getrefnumber{myNiceLemma}

Cref: \Cref{myNiceLemma}

But how can I get ``\texttt{theorem.2}'' here?

\getanchor{myNiceLemma}

\end{document}



Perfect, thank you!
